# Using optional **kwargs in python

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am in process of refactoring a codebase in Python where I am still learning their syntactical sugar so hopefully I can get some help from the experts here.

I want to write a generic function that takes list of optional arguments using `**kwargs` and makes a call to DB model using the list of arguments present. So for eg 5 out of 8 column entries are present in the function call, make a create call using those 5 (rest 3 are already accept null in DB). However if I send 7 values in function, I should be able to use the same function again.

So here is something I am thinking of :

**Controller Class**
....

```
create(arg1=x, arg3=y, arg4=z, arg6=a, arg7=b)

create(arg1=x, arg2=x2, arg3=y, arg4=z, arg6=a, arg7=b, arg8=b2)
```

....

**Model Class**

```
    arg1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    arg2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    arg3 = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    arg4 = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    arg5 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    arg6 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    arg7 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    arg8 = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True)
  

    def create(**kwargs):
        DBMODEL.objects.create(
            arg1=kwargs['arg1'],
            arg2=kwargs['arg2'],
            arg3=kwargs['arg3'],
            arg4=kwargs['arg4'],
            arg5=kwargs['arg5'],
            arg6=kwargs['arg6'],
            arg7=kwargs['arg7'],
            arg8=kwargs['arg8']
        )
```

Is that something which can be done using my code above or if there is any other suggestion?

End goal is to have a single function to take care of multiple calls with different number of arguments without having multiple if and else in the model class function being called.

Any suggestions/ideas will be appreciated. This is something where official doc didn't help me much.

Comment: To support this, you can do `DBMODEL.objects.create(**kwargs)`

Comment: @BrianDestura Great. I can give this a shot. And is it even possible to unzip this list and add another param before I call `create` method?

Comment: Yes! If you are new to python I think you might find [this](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/) really helpful

Answer (score 0):

`create` method accepts `**kwargs` so can be used like this:

```py
values = {"field1": 1, "field2": 2, "field3": 3}
DBMODEL.objects.create(**values)  # same as DBMODEL.objects.create(field1=1, field=2, field3=3)

values = {"field1": 1, "field2": 2, "field3": 3, "field4": 4}
DBMODEL.objects.create(**values). # same as DBMODEL.objects.create(field1=1, field=2, field3=3, field4=4)
```

Comment: That's what I am trying to avoid. it can be any possible permutations of arguments. So I may pass 1, 3, 4 or 1,4,6 or all 8 or something like that. If there is a way to have a single liner to take care of it just like **kwargs

Comment: Just past `**kwargs` to `create` method `DBMODEL.objects.create(**kwargs)`